# RMI multithread skeleton

Tags: java, multithreading, rmi

My application use rmi for serve client request to manipulate data on a database (using JDBC). I would like that skeleton run a thread for each client's operation request. I need just to to something like

```
public MySkeleton implement MyInterface {
    public string method1() {
        myThread.start();
    }
```

or something else?

Comment: Definitely not `run()`. Threads are started with `Thread#start()`.

Comment: OK, now your thread will start and execute either the `run` method you overrode in it, or the one from a `Runnable` you passed in its constructor.

Comment: just pass the Myinterface instance to the Runnable impl to run something like this [link](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#trpool)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like that skeleton run a thread for each client's operation request.

RMI already does that.

> I need just to to something like

No you don't. Just write the method normally. RMI will multithread it for you.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to do anything special whatsoever, the RMI framework takes care of spinning off new threads automatically for you. Try it with the simplest server possible, you will see that every time a new client connects it is always able to connect to the server straightaway:

```
public interface Server extends java.rmi.Remote {
    void doIt () throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
}

public class ServerImpl extends java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject implements Server {
    public ServerImpl() throws java.rmi.RemoteException {
            super();
    }

    public void doIt () {
            System.out.println ("Starting in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            try { Thread.sleep(10000); } catch(InterruptedException t) {}
            System.out.println ("Stopping in " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }

    public static void main (String[] argv) throws Exception {
            java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            java.rmi.Naming.rebind ("//localhost/Server", new ServerImpl ());
    }
}

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
            ((Server) java.rmi.Naming.lookup("Server")).doIt();
    }
}
```